# Почему не работает quick view woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Вывел категорию в шаблон страницы, вот таким шорткодом.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[product_category per_page="4" orderby="date" order="desc" category="barcode-scanner"]');?>
```

Поставил плагин yith quick view, но модальное окно не работает (т.е он вообще не появляется). Кнопка от quick view есть и у него id "#". В чем может быть проблема? Может в шорткоде что то не дописал? в документации пишется, что нужно установить плагин и появится кнопка, которая будет выводить модальное окно.

Comment: Смотри ошибки в консоли браузера

Comment: В консоли нет ошибок

Comment: Если я правильно помню yith работает через ajax, посмотри отправляется ли ajax запрос, посмотри что возвращает ajax запрос. Возможно ты получаешь ошибку при ajax

Comment: Если через ajax, то я должен был, где то заполнить сначала данные, что бы  было что возвращать? Верно?

Comment: это делает yith,  у кнопки быстрого просмотра есть параметр data-product_id с которым работает yith

Comment: @Darth KYL Спасибо, посмотрю